# Multiple API calling one after another in Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I need to call `http://sample.com` multiple times depending on the number of `data`.
After that I also need to call `http://sample2.com` multiple times after calling `http://sample.com` since the response from `http://sample.com` is need to be pass to `http://sample2.com`.

I need to know how can I make them all finished before calling the success dispatch properly?

```
export const createAllProducts =
  ({ data = null, isCall2 = false }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
      });

      const requests = data.map(({ test, name }) => {
        return getAxiosService().post("http://sample.com", {
          test,
          name,
        });
      });

      const responses = await Promise.all(requests);


      const productCode = responses?.map(({ code }, index) => {
        if (!productCode) throw new Error("Code not found");
        if (isCall2)
          await getAxiosService().post("http://sample2.com", {
            code,
          })
      });
      

      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: You can change the line `const productCode = responses?.map(({ code }, index) => {` to  `await Promise.all(responses?.map(async ({ code }, index)=> {` to invoke the API calls in parallel and wait for all them to complete.

Comment: @user1672994. are you able to put it as answer? the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the API calls in parallel and wait for all those to complete, you need change the code to following

```
if (isCall2 && responses) { 
     await Promise.all(responses.map(async ({ code }, index) => {          
        await getAxiosService().post("http://sample2.com", {
            code,
        });
     }));
}
```

Full code:

```
export const createAllProducts =
  ({ data = null, isCall2 = false }) =>
   async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
      });

      const requests = data.map(({ test, name }) => {
        return getAxiosService().post("http://sample.com", {
          test,
          name,
        });
      });

      const responses = await Promise.all(requests);

      if (isCall2 && responses) { 
        await Promise.all(responses.map(async ({ code }, index) =>{          
          await getAxiosService().post("http://sample2.com", {
            code,
          });
        }));
    }
      
    dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_ALL_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: How about the others? Is it good already. Maybe you can put it here?

Comment: You can change the first one too. But is seems looking good as you are already doing waiting for async call to complete via `const responses = await Promise.all(requests);`

Comment: Can you put the whole code? and also I think this is incorrect `if (!productCode) throw new Error("Code not found");`

Comment: @Joseph - I've updated the answer to remove the `if` condition of product code and also moved the `if(isCall2)` as first check along with validating responses object.

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to put the whole code?

Comment: Sure, let me add the full code after change.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing `data` array contains a property`productUniqueNumber`. I also need it to be pass to `http://sample2.com`. Can you add it too?

Comment: @Joseph - data itself is array. How it would be joining with responses that has to be defined. Also, I would suggest you if need further refining in your question then you can post another question instead of updating the current question or comment.

Comment: Nevemind. anyway thanks a lot